# Trying to get property of non-object all though it does exist

Tags: php, object

I know this was asked alot but i have this code :

```
    foreach($prices as $price){

$provider_id = $price->provider_id;
$prod_id = $price->product_id;
$name = $price->prod_name;
$desc = $price->desc;
$price = $price->price;
$original_price = $price->original_price;
$reward = $price->reward;
    }
```

Now if i `print_r` it i get :

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1214
    [price_list_id] => 123
    [product_id] => 136
    [provider_id] => 1
    [price] => 0
    [reward] => 0
    [original_price] => 135
    [prod_name] => some text
    [desc] => some text with ' and " and ,
)
```

Any idea what could cause this? i get the error on `original_price` and `reward`

Comment: What variable are you passing to `print_r()`?

Comment: @coder1984 "trying to get property of non-object" and nickb i'm passing $price

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the error, you have `2 variables` named `$price` in the loop,

```
 $price = $price->price;
```

And,

```
 foreach($prices as $price){
```

Comment: Damn havn't even thought about that... Thank you!